# How can I generate data from a plotted line in R?

Tags: r, scatter, standard-deviation, line-plot, data-generation

I have no dataset just two plotted lines and I want to generate scattered y-axis data 2 standard deviations away from the mean (the plotted line). Here is my code for the line:

```
ggplot() +
 lims(x = c(0,20), y = c(0,1)) + 
 annotate("segment",x = .1,xend = 5, yend = .25, y = .1) +
 annotate("segment",x = 5,xend = 20, yend = .35,y = .25)
```

[image: This graph should help describe what I am trying to do.]

Sorry if this post is unclear but I am not sure the best way to explain it. Let me know if you have any questions or if what I am trying to do isn't possible.

Comment: What you are trying to do is possible. 1) Fit lines to your segments (such that you get the y=ax+b for each one) 2) choose x values to get the y values you call "mean". 3) use `rnorm(n, mean)` for each of your x so that you get the distribution you are after

Comment: Okay, I sorta understand what you are saying. 1) I found the slopes (0.09 and 0.0067)and I changed my lines so the intercept would be 0 to simplify things. 2) My x values are discretely 1:20. I get that I can plug them into the equation to find y. 3) I don't understand the what or why of this step.

Comment: Number 3 is per your request of generating scattered data around each y(x) value. You should plug whatever sd you want

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for one of the lines you have (I didn't double check whether `y = 0.09*x + 0` is consistent or not with what you showed, guiding my answer from your comment).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(x=1:20,
       y1=0.09*x,
       y2=0.0067*x)

# generate dots for y1
# mean y1 and sd = 1

sapply(df$y1, function(tt) rnorm(10, tt)) %>% 
  # make it into tibble
  as_tibble() %>% 
  # pivot into longer format
  tidyr::pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  # names of the columns get assigned to V1 V2 ... 
  # we can clean that and get the actual x
  # this works nicely because your x=1:20, will fail otherwise
  mutate(X=as.numeric(stringr::str_remove(name, "V"))) %>%  
  # plot the thing
  ggplot(aes(X, value)) +
  geom_point() +
  # add the "mean" values from before
  geom_point(data=df, aes(x, y1), col="red", size=2)
```

[image]